# How to pull data from Oracle to MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-connector

We have a requirment where we have to pull the data from Oracle database to MariaDB from where the Application access that data.

Can some please help me how can we accomplish this?

Thank you

I am aware of data link where we can pull the data Fro mariaDB to Oracle but not sure in reverse way

Answer (score 2):

The [MariaDB Connect Engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/introduction-to-the-connect-engine/) has [ODBC](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-odbc-table-type-accessing-tables-from-another-dbms/) and [JDBC](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-jdbc-table-type-accessing-tables-from-another-dbms/) data types which can connect to Oracle.

Rough instructions:

1. install MariaDB-connect-engine and unixODBC
2. configure the Oracle ODBC driver in /etc/odbcinst.ini
3. configure a Oracle DSN to the server in ~/.odbc.ini
4. load the `ha_connect.so` into MariaDB (`plugin-load-add=ha_connect.so` in `my.cnf`)
5. create mariadb table connecting to Oracle - `create table table_maria engine=connect table_type=ODBC tabname='t' Connection='DSN=oracle' SRCDEF='select * from t';`
6. create local table; `create table table_maria_local like table_maria; alter table table_maria_local engine=InnoDB`
7. copy data; `insert into table_maria_local select * from table_maria`

Extracted from [blog](https://mariadb.org/data-migration-from-oracle-to-mariadb-with-docker-and-connect-se-a-step-by-step-guide/)